# Best Option for emailing SSRS reports

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Okay I have built an SSRS report with a parameter.  This parameter designates group a or group b.  From there I have a subset list of emails that need this report to be sent to.  For example Group A has a 4 different groups that the report needs to be mailed to. Which each of the 4 different groups have their own information that will be sent.  We currently do not have subscriptions activated on the server so I was wondering which way would be the best way to handle this scenario?  We are using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The best way would be with subscriptions. Is activating those an option?

Comment: Since subscription is not an option, I ended up building an ssis package that loops through accounts and renders the report in excel then gathers the emails for that account and then sends the email with the rendered excel documents.